# Crash in Firefox extension Using NSS

Tags: firefox, dll, firefox-addon, pkcs#7, nss

I am new to Firefox extension development.

We got a firefox Extension that signs PDF (encapsulated signature) working for all versions of firefox prior to 22 (22 not included) Using NSS 3.12. After that Firefox version, there is a modification in the NSS used by it. 
This extension is a JS extension calling C++ fonctions using ctypes.

My goal is to make this extension work on firefox version superior to 22.

I got in my extension libs nspr4.dll, nss3.dll, nssutil3.dll, plc4.dll, plds4.dll generated with mozilla-build from NSS release.

the Code we got is pretty similar to what you can find here : https://github.com/metajack/nss/blob/master/cmd/p7sign/p7sign.c

the code works well ( it gets the certificates information sucessfully, creates the SEC_PKCS7ContentInfo with SEC_PKCS7CreateSignedData(...), set it's content with SEC_PKCS7SetContent(..), includes the certs chains)
until the call of SEC_PKCS7Encode.
when using this method, fireFox crashes.

I used WinDBG to get the stacktrace and here is what I got:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                           Exception Analysis                                *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


FAULTING_IP: 
plds4!PL_HashTableLookupConst+c
721b1c7c 8b4f0c          mov     ecx,dword ptr [edi+0Ch]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
.exr 0xffffffffffffffff
ExceptionAddress: 00000000721b1c7c (plds4!PL_HashTableLookupConst+0x000000000000000c)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 000000000000000c
Attempt to read from address 000000000000000c

CONTEXT:  0000000000000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
.cxr 0x0;r
eax=063e7b90 ebx=00000000 ecx=dd4c128b edx=063e7c98 esi=063e7b90 edi=00000000
eip=721b1c7c esp=0067c1e8 ebp=063e7898 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00210206
plds4!PL_HashTableLookupConst+0xc:
721b1c7c 8b4f0c          mov     ecx,dword ptr [edi+0Ch] ds:002b:0000000c=????????
.cxr

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000000000016cc

PROCESS_NAME:  firefox.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - L

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - L

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000000000000c

READ_ADDRESS:  000000000000000c 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
plds4!PL_HashTableLookupConst+c
721b1c7c 8b4f0c          mov     ecx,dword ptr [edi+0Ch]

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  firefox.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17029 (debuggers(dbg).140219-1702) amd64fre

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_ZEROED_STACK

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000716b9231 to 00000000721b1c7c

STACK_TEXT:  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0067c1f4 716b9231 00000000 063e7b90 063e7ca0 plds4!PL_HashTableLookupConst+0xc
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 nssutil3!SECOID_FindOIDTag_Util+0x11


STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0x0 ; kb

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  plds4!PL_HashTableLookupConst+c

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: plds4

IMAGE_NAME:  plds4.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53a04c1e

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_c0000005_plds4.dll!PL_HashTableLookupConst

BUCKET_ID:  
APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_ZEROED_STACK_plds4!PL_HashTableLookupConst+c

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:                          um:null_class_ptr_read_c0000005_plds4.dll!pl_hashtablelookupconst

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {2f7bb160-6820-dd99-35e3-03bb56e8aca4}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

It means that when calling the SEC_PKCS7Encode, it calls a method in PLDS4.DLL that make Firefox crash.

I tried to call SEC_PKCS7Encode using an empty SEC_PKCS7ContentInfo (with SEC_PKCS7CreateData()) and it didn't crash. It crashes only when the SEC_PKCS7ContentInfo is filled.

After some reaserchs , I find this issue : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702307 
I don't know if this issue is what makes my Firefox crash.

I tried to use different version of the NSS (3.12,  3.15, 3.16.2) the results are exactly the same.

Is there some way to avoid this problem ? is there a way to encode my SEC_PKCS7ContentInfo whithout using SEC_PKCS7Encode ?

thanks in advance.

EDIT 11/07/2014

As nmaier mentioned in is response, the probleme seems to be the utilisation of two different NSS (even if it is the same version of the nss because the one in mozilla has different dependencies for exemple).

The signature (and other processes) are done in a C++ project (the Dll used by my extension is generated from this project with visual studio 2013). But in order to compile and build the DLL, the project must have the NSS libs and includes (it is quite normal, I use NSS methods in my project).
The main question is how can I refer the MOZILLA FIREFOX NSS libs and include. I compiled a NSS of the same version of the Firefox's NSS, but the dependecies are different. 
I also tried to get the FireFox sources and compile it's NSS with mozilla build but I got errors. If I can get the Firefox's NSS libs, I could just load the Firefox's NSS dll in my extension.

How can I refers Mozilla firefox's NSS libs in my C++ project to build my custom DLL using the right libs ?

Comment: You certainly mean `C` functions, not `C++` functions (ctypes doesn't support the latter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did It.

In order to specify firefox's NSS in my project, I had to build an entire Firefox with the mozilla-build tool, and then recover the Libs and include for inside the OBJ directory.

this will generate my project as DLL that refers the good version of the DLL.

(this is not the greatest solution I think, as there is a NSS changement of the NSS between Firefox  21 and  22, so my solution will only work for firefox between 22 and the next version of Firefox that include NSS changes.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect this to misbehave: Firefox already load nss and dependent libraries. Trying to load the "same" DLL again, but in a different version will cause the DLL loader to resolve dependent imports using the exports from the initially loaded DLL that comes with Firefox, not your copies of older versions of the same DLL. And this mix of new stuff and old stuff then breaks and crashes.

You should:

- Not build and ship DLLs in the first place...
- but use the DLLs that Firefox already comes with. (e.g. see [`WeaveCrypto.js`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e268bb51e084/services/crypto/modules/WeaveCrypto.js#l123))
- Update your `ctypes` calls if the nss API it uses changed in the meantime.
- Make sure your `ctypes` declarations are correct and still up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact I already have a C++ project that uses the NSS and make all the process I want. My IDE is visual Studio 2010. The probleme is that I don't know how to refer the Firefox NSS in my project that generate the DLL. It only accept NSS libs dans include in my project, so I can only refer home made built NSS (with mozilla build)(I don't have the libs and includes of the firefox built NSS DLL).

Comment: I'm not sure I quite got that... You have a custom DLL that links the nss libraries. And ctypes would interact with that custom DLL, but not with the nss libraries directly?

Comment: Exactly, the custom DLL do all the signing and specifics process calling the NSS, but in order to build that DLL, I have to refer in visual Studio (my building tool) the NSS libs.